# O365: managed property: managed property only text and yes/no

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, managed-property, content-search-web-part

I need to create a managed property in SP online (E3).

When I click on create, the options I have available for type of data are only Text and yes/no. All the others are grayed out. I need date and time and it is grayed out.

Is this normal or there is something wrong with my account and/or some other settings?

I need to create a managed property to use the PublishedDate (of the blog) in the CSWP

Comment: Sadly, this is normal for SPO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked in my tenant. It looks like its normal. I logged in using Global Admin, but still the properties are disabled.

What I usually do, map the crawled properties to the OOTB properties like:

1. RefinableString
2. RefinableDate
3. RefinableDateInvariant
4. RefinableDecimal
5. RefinableDouble
6. RefinableInt

Now, after mapping, I usually reindex the site collection and wait for it get populated. Takes around 24 hours to get the value.

In your case, boolean can be mapped to RefinableString while the PublishedDate can be mapped to RefinableString or RefinableDate. You can then use these properties in your CSWP webparts

There are lots of OOTB 'Refinable...' properties available and if you have exhausted them, just raise a support ticket and MS will add them in your tenant.

[image]

Comment: Do you recommend renaming the Refinable19? or just write an alias in the alias field?

Comment: Alias would be just fine.